# Java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, bluej

In my program that turns roman numerals into arabic numbers I have run across the error

> incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted into int

Here is my code

```
if ( Character.isDigit(TextIO.peek()) ) {
    int arabic = TextIO.getlnInt();
    try {
        RomanNumerals N = new RomanNumerals(arabic);
        TextIO.putln(N.toInt() + " = " + N.toString());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
else {
    String roman = TextIO.getln();
    try {
        RomanNumerals N = new RomanNumerals(roman);
        System.out.println(N.toString() + " = " + N.toInt());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am using BlueJ and the error is being highlighted over "(roman)"

Comment: The constructor for `RomanNumerals` must expect an `int`, and you're giving it a `String`. You need to convert it into an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guesswork here... but probably your class RomanNumerals does not have a constructor taking a string as an argument like

```
public RomanNumerals(String r) {
```

Thats why calling it that way:

```
RomanNumerals N = new RomanNumerals(roman);
```

Is not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at `TextIO.putln(N.toInt() + " = " + N.toString());` and imagining that `N.toInt()` returns an `int` and the compiler is confused when you try adding `" = "` to it.

Try `TextIO.putln(Integer(N.toInt()).toString() + " = " + N.toString());`.